# How to efficiently convert a list into a map?

Tags: python

For example, I have a list like:

my_list = ['a', 'b', 'c']

I want to convert it as: for each element as a key, the other elements will be a list of values, so the example above will be converted to:

```
my_dict = {'a': ['b', 'c'], 'b': ['a', 'c'], 'c': ['a', 'b']}
```

This is what I did

```
for l in my_list:
   my_dict[l] = [e for e in my_list if e != l]
```

Is there a better way to do it?

Comment: What kind of "better" do you have in mind? Did you measure e.g. memory consumption or runtime? Do you need the whole dict? How often?

Comment: Like I said in the title,  'efficiently', so I mean speed optimization.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suppose you could just take slices of the list in a dict comprehension. This avoid looping with the inner comprehension and keeps the order in a readable way:

```
my_list = ['a', 'b', 'c']

d = {k: my_list[:i] + my_list[i+1:] for i, k in enumerate(my_list)}  
# {'a': ['b', 'c'], 'b': ['a', 'c'], 'c': ['a', 'b']}
```

Timings suggest its a fair amount faster:

```
my_list = list(range(1000))

%timeit d = {k: my_list[:i] + my_list[i+1:] for i, k in enumerate(my_list)}
# 8.03 ms ± 123 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

my_dict = {}

%timeit for l in my_list: my_dict[l] = [e for e in my_list if e != l]
# 51.4 ms ± 491 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```

Answer (score 2):

try this:

```
def remove_el(arr, el):
    arr.remove(el)
    return arr

my_dict = {ml : remove_el(my_list[:],ml) for ml in (my_list)}
# {'a': ['b', 'c'], 'b': ['a', 'c'], 'c': ['a', 'b']}

my_list = ['a', 'b', 'c']
%timeit my_dict = {ml : remove_el(my_list[:],ml) for ml in (my_list)}
# 1.09 µs ± 17.5 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)
```

Runtime of another answer:

```
my_list = ['a', 'b', 'c']
%timeit d = {k: my_list[:i] + my_list[i+1:] for i, k in enumerate(my_list)}
# 1.22 µs ± 8.72 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)
```

Comment: I would suggest a test on a larger list like you had earlier. `remove()` needs to scan the list to find items, which means it gets slower as the list grows. It’s not bad, but anything will do okay on 3 elements.

Comment: @Mark you can edit your answer and add this comment on your answer

Comment: BTW, the time taken is not the only thing that matters in optimisation.

Comment: @PCM no doubt, but the OP did specify speed.

Comment: @Mark, where? It mentions efficiency

Comment: @Mark i understand what you say. i suggest checking my answer runtime on your own answer

Comment: @PCM their comment under the question.

Answer (score 0):

Use Dictionary Comprehension because it can be more (elegant?) faster and readable -

```
my_list = ['a', 'b', 'c']
mydict = {ele:[string for string in my_list if string != ele] for ele in my_list}

print(mydict) # {'a': ['b', 'c'], 'b': ['a', 'c'], 'c': ['a', 'b']}
```